# What does the following mean in javascript? !!"false"

Tags: javascript

What does the following mean in **javascript** and How does it evaluate to a result true.

```
!!"false"
```

Would there by any need to use such an expression.

Comment: Generally for having a boolean value. A string is a truthy value in JavaScript, `negation -> true to false`, again `false to true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this one is tricky if you assume that "false" evaluates to boolean false. Know that, unless it's an empty string, "", that a string will always evaluate to true. So, you are basically saying, not not true. Double-negative cancels out, thus, true.

Answer (score 1):

Every non-empty string is considered true. So when you double negate something that's true, you get true again.

Code like that can be used to get the boolean value from a non-boolean variable, for example.

Answer (score 1):

That means not not a truely value string, so you'll end up with `true` (boolean).

Answer (score 1):

You should recall which things in Java are *truthy* and *falsy*–which items convert to true and false in logical contexts:

### Falsy

1. `false`
2. `null`
3. `undefined`
4. `0`
5. `NaN`
6. `''`

## Truthy

1. `true`
2. non-zero numbers (other than `NaN`).
3. non-empty strings
4. objects, including wrapped versions of primitives.
5. arrays

Note that `new Boolean(false)` is *truthy*. Don't wrap primitives.

Now the `!` operator takes `false` to `true` and back. For any other value, it takes the logical interpretation converting to `boolean`, and then flips it.  So, `!"false"` first interprets `"false"` as `true` since nonempty strings are truthy. Then, it computes `!true`, and gets `false`.

Using a second `!` operator will then convert the `false` to `true`. Given a *truthy* argument `x`, `!!x` will be `true`.  Given a *falsy* argument `y`, `!!y` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It is done to evaluate a non-boolean value as if was a boolean, any value will be evaluated as true except: undefined, null, 0, false or empty string ("").